# Why do we use $model = new ModelName('search') in action admin?

Tags: yii

Even if we create the object normally it works in action admin then why do we use search argument while creating the object?

I don't understand the usage of the following code which sends `id` along with the search while creating the `modelobject` like

```
$model=new ModelName('search&id='.$_GET['id']);
```

Comment: these are two questions or one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That argument means model Scenario which tells model which scenario to use in any place that scenario is needed like validations. Here documentation says:

> __construct() method public void __construct(string
>   $scenario='insert') $scenario string scenario name. See
>   CModel::scenario for more details about this parameter.

And the docs concerning `CModel::scenario` documents:

> **scenario property** public string getScenario() public void setScenario(string $value)
>
> Returns the scenario that this model is used in.
>
> Scenario affects how validation is performed and which attributes can
>   be massively assigned.
>
> A validation rule will be performed when calling validate() if its
>   'on' option is not set or contains the current scenario value.
>
> And an attribute can be massively assigned if it is associated with a
>   validation rule for the current scenario. Note that an exception is
>   the unsafe validator which marks the associated attributes as unsafe
>   and not allowed to be massively assigned.

Simply said it means create new model and tell it we are in searching scenario.

Comment: Thanks Stefano, but what is the need for passing the id along with scenario ('search')

Comment: you need to add new method that will do that or extend AR class and make constructor of your own!

Answer (score 2):

So you want to pass a value to the Search method within your model? When calling the method:

```
$model = new ModelName::model()->search($_GET['id']);
```

And in the `search()` method in the model, modify like so:

```
public function search($id){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks eskimo, But I want to know what happens or how it would affect the variable $model.

Comment: The variable $model is just a object containing a record set of whatever model you are querying. So in my example above, it won't do anything to the $model value. It all depends on what you do with the passed $id value in the method. What is it you are looking to do?

Comment: this is what I was looking for but it shows error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'`  Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `zii.widgets.grid.CGridView` in your View then you can pass parameter as

`'dataProvider'=>$model->search($id)` and in search scenario in Model accept this parameter.